# How to assign phonegap device.platform value to a variable?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'd like to assign the value in device.platform to a variable so I can check it later in my program. 
For example, if the app is running on a BlackBerry I might want to have a custom message appear.

I used the "element" example found elsewhere to make sure things were working properly (and it does). But I run into problems when I try assigning just the "device.platform" value to devicePlatform.

I've been fighting with this for an hour, I must be missing something fairly basic.
Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Rob

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      // wait for PhoneGap to load
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
      //
    }
    </script>    

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello PhoneGap v1.9.0</h1>

    <script>
      var devicePlatform = device.platform;
      document.write("Platform: "+devicePlatform+"<br>");    
    </script>
    <br>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting

```
var devicePlatform = device.platform;
document.write("Platform: "+devicePlatform+"<br>");
```

into the function onDeviceReady()

This should resolve the issue.

Additionally you will probably want to define a globally scoped variable, such as 'platform' and then assign the device.platform to that variable in the function onDeviceReady().

Example:

```
var platform = null;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  platform = device.platform;
  alert(platform);
}
```

UPDATE:

I think this is closer to what you are looking for

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      // wait for PhoneGap to load
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('platformarea');
        element.innerHTML = device.platform;
      //
    }
    </script>    

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello PhoneGap v1.9.0</h1>

    <p id="platformarea"></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's almost working. The document.write and alert work as you said when they're in the onDeviceReady function. But when I try to use "platform" elsewhere later in the program it returns the initial value of "null" instead of the device.platform value. Thanks

Comment: You will only be able to display 'platform' after the function onDeviceReady() fires. Could you add some code for where you are trying to use 'platform'? Thanks

Comment: Using this in the <body> shows initial value ("null"). It's almost like "platform" isn't being treated as a global variable.  
    <script>
      document.write("Platform: "+platform+"<br>");    
    </script>

Comment: The issue that the function onDeviceReady() is not called until after the page is fully rendered, so you will not be able to use platform in the body. Just like the example you posted, you have to created a placeholder container with an id and then use JS to load the content into it after the function onDeviceReady() is called. I can post another example if that would help.

Comment: Ahhh. Now I see what's been causing me problems. It's a basic misunderstanding, I thought everything in the <head> was completed before the <body> was rendered.  Thank you very much for clearing that up for me!!  Rob

Comment: Just to add, I was having an issue where `device.platform` was always set to null on device ready but `window.device.platform` was correctly set.

Answer (score 2):

Insted of using `device.platform`, you can use `cordova.platformId`.
I'm sure it will help

Comment: The above accepted answer does not appear to work in the latest version of Phonegap, but this does.

Comment: Working at cordova 4.3.0

Comment: If I have to assign a value to cordova.platformId how can I do that? I mean like creating a mock object of cordova.platformId. like I tried to assign cordova.platformId="android" but it doesnot work